# Внешние папки в проекте Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

Использую CI. У меня есть папка `projects` в корне, где находятся папки с проектами к каждой которой есть файл `index.php` в который включен фрейм.
Когда я пытаюсь открыть файл по ссылке `site.com/projects/folder/index.php` я получаю ошибку 404, так как CI обращается к контролеру и не находит функции.

Как открыть файл в директории projects не получая 404 от фреймверка?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, через .htaccess не отправлять запрос на корневой index.php.
Замените

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

на

```
RewriteCond $1 !^projects/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```